# Creating a Romberg Integration Function in Python

Tags: python, math, numerical-analysis

I have a python function for Romberg Integration as follows:

```
def romberg(f,a,b,n):
     RArray = numpy.zeros(shape=(n,n))
     for i in range(0,n):
          RArray[i,0]=trapezoidRule(f,a,b,i+1)
     for k in range(1,n):
          for j in range(1,k):
               RArray[k,j]=RArray[k,j-i]+((RArray[k,j-1]-RArray[k-1,j-1])/(4**(j-1)-1))
     return RArray
```

where trapezoidRule is the function

```
def trapezoidRule(f,a,b,n):
     h=float((b-a)/n)
     ans=(f(a)/2)+(f(b)/2)
     for i in range(1,n):
          ans+=f(a+(i*h))
     ans=ans*h
     return ans
```

the parameters I am sending in are:

```
f = lambda x: (3/(1+x**5))
a=0
b=2
n=4
```

but I'm getting a RuntimeWarning and not getting the RArray that I want. Can someone help me figure out what the problem is? (I'm pretty sure my ranges are wrong in my romberg function but anyway I adjust them I still get an error or a warning)

Answer (score 0):

In line 7, when you divide by `(4**(j-1) - 1)`, when `j == 0`, this becomes zero.
That's why you get a "divide by zero" RuntimeWarning.